# Basic Oracle Procedure - Refuses to work

Tags: oracle, procedure

I am trying to implement a simple procedure in Oracle, and I'm really at my wits end as to how to do it.

```
Create  PROCEDURE Getcustomername33(

wcust_id varchar2                   --Input parameter ,  Studentid of the student 

)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT Firstname+' '+Lastname FROM customer WHERE cust_id=wcust_id
END​;​
```

This gives an error saying sql command not properly. However if i run it again it says name is already in use by an existing object. So its deliberately creating a procedure that isint working?? I can't understand how this is so difficult. It also sometimes says "Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: ( begin case declare" etc

Help is massively appreciated,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
Create OR UPDATE PROCEDURE Getcustomername33(

wcust_id varchar2                   --Input parameter ,  Studentid of the student 

)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT Firstname || ' ' || Lastname FROM customer WHERE cust_id=wcust_id
END​;
```

​I guess Oracle saves the stored Procedure and then tries to compile it... yours is failing in compilation, so its already exists on server 2nd time..

Comment: I can see three mistakes in this. This won't even compile.  1) 'Create or Update procedure' is wrong. 2) A variable should be defined and query should SELECT into that variable. 3) Semicolon missing at the end of the SELECT statement.

Comment: @Noel if you see the question, it was for 2 things 1. the error in OP's code and why Oracle says that object already exists when its not compiled successfully. My intention was to answer that two rather than giving full working code. And thats why I think the answer was accepted too.

Answer (score 1):

concatenation doesn't work like this in PLSQL, you should do:

```
Firstname || ' ' || Lastname
```